# IntelliJ Package Checker not finding vulnerabilities

Tags: security, intellij-idea, cve

As said in the title, I cannot find any vulnerabilities in my project using the bundled Package Search plugin to find dependencies vulnerabilities.

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3 (Ultimate Edition), and I checked it by putting for example the spring-boot-starter-parent version to 2.2.1.RELEASE, which contains severe CVE vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So In fact yes it works perfectly and is awesome.
But was bugged in previous version.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-294147/Intellij-IDEA-show-vulnerable-dependencies-not-working-when-an-IDE-is-activated-not-with-JetBrains-Account

MY colleague had his personal licence activation before using the company licence server, that's why it worked on his side.

Answer (score -1):

package-checker works fine as is out of the box with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)

it's quite awesome, actually

i do have colleagues where it is not working with intellij-c though, which would be nice to resolve